# Proof that "holomorphic implies continuously differentiable" using real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am interested in how one could prove that $H(\Omega)\subset \mathscr C^1(\Omega)$ without using the Cauchy integral formula, or any other complex analytic techniques, only real analysis.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That said, it's probably possible to show that $\bar\partial$ is elliptic, or at least hypoelliptic using purely real methods.

Comment: But I'm afraid this will not be enough : it does not seem obvious that if a function $f$ is holomorphic (i.e. just differentiable in the complex sense) then $\overline\partial f=0$ in the distribution sense.